# Laravel 5.5: Events not fired on Pivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I recently migrate from L5.3 to L5.5 and add new pivot class to my Shop model called ShopProductPivot and to monitor events I add events to both "Shop" and "ShopProductPivot" (details is omitted for the sake of simplicity):

```
class Shop extends Model{
    protected $table = 'shops';
    protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'title');

    public function productSKUs(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductSKU',
            'shop_products', 'shop_id', 'sku_id')
            ->withPivot(['price', 'discount', 'transport_price', 'in_stock'])
            ->using('App\ShopProductPivot');
    }

    public static function boot(){
        parent::boot();

        Pivot::creating(function($pivot) {
            dump("pivot_creating");
        });

        Pivot::created(function($pivot) {
            dump("pivot_created");
        });

        Pivot::saving(function($pivot) {
            dump("pivot_saving");
        });

        Pivot::saved(function($pivot) {
            dump("pivot_saved");
        });

        Pivot::updating(function($pivot) {
            dump("pivot_updating");
        });

        Pivot::updated(function($pivot) {
            dump("pivot_updated");
        });
    }
}

class ShopProductPivot extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'shop_products';
    protected $fillable = array('shop_id', 'sku_id', 'price', 'in_stock');

    public static function boot(){
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($pivot) {
            dump("creating");
        });

        static::created(function($pivot) {
            dump("created");
        });

        static::saving(function($pivot) {
            dump("saving");
        });

        static::saved(function($pivot) {
            dump("saved");
        });

        static::updating(function($pivot) {
            dump("updating");
        });

        static::updated(function($pivot) {
            dump("updated");
        });
    }
}
```

By running the following command I expect some events fired but nothing happen to me!

```
$shop->productSKUs()->attach([
    101 => ['price'=> mt_rand(10,99)*10, 'in_stock'=> true],
    102 => ['price'=> mt_rand(10,99)*10, 'in_stock'=> true]
]);
```

Comment: https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-pivot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pivot models in Laravel 5.5. do not fire events when you use the `attach` method on a model with a `BelongsToMany` relationship.

Why?

Instead of going the usual `create` route when the Eloquent models are created, when you attach related models, Laravel uses `insert` method of `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`. Unlike `create`, `update`, `save` and  `delete` methods of the Eloquent model, Query Builder methods do not fire any events. Having the Pivot model defined on a pivot relationship does not change this.

If you want to achieve such functionality, you may want to consider using [Laravel Pivot](https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-pivot) package, already mentioned in the comments by its author.